# While in Safe-Mode user should not have any access to application

Tags: android

When emulator is running is safe mode, my application is not visible to user but On HTC-G1 run in safe mode , its visible to the user. How can I keep the app invisible on device also while its runing in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

That is not for you to control. That is between the operating system and the user. This is a good thing, because otherwise people would use this to create and perpetuate malware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
But now my requirement is: how can I prevent a user to access/invoke the application while device is runing in safe mode.